# Error: Mysqld.socket is Missing

Tags: command-line, apt, server, mysql

I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04.2. I installed php7.2 and then started to install mysql:

I used

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
//This part of the installation finished without errors
$ mysql_secure_installation
//Here the error occured
```

I recieved the following error message:

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

After going to the directory that the error pointed to, I got to /var/run and /mysqld did not exist.

Here is the mysql status

```
$sudo service mysql status

● mysql.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

After unmasking using:

```
$ systemctl unmask mysql.service
```

The mysql status changed

```
$sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

But the same error continued when using mysql_secure_instalation

I thought about creating the mysqld directory but I wouldn't have the mysqld.sock anyway. I found people with a similar problem, but it was post-installation and their solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: please post the output of `sudo service mysql status`?

Comment: Just edited the post and put it there

Comment: that's your issue, unmask your MySql and run with `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: How do I unmask mysql?

Comment: to unmask, I used: 
~~~
$ systemctl unmask mysql.service
~~~
but I'm still getting the same error
though mysql status now returns this:
~~~
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: inactive (dead)
~~~

Comment: after that, try to restart your service and start it again.

Comment: I've already fixed it, by reinstalling ubuntu from scratch, I think I deleted a file I shouldn't have. I wanted to clean everything anyway so it wasn't any trouble. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to fix this problem I had, but I fixed it by reinstalling ubuntu. A rudimentary fix, but it worked.